# Firestore trigger function not fired

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created a trigger function in Firestore that is to supposed to fire every time a document is created.

```js
export const appsDocumentCreated = onDocumentCreated('apps/{appId}', async (event) => {
  const logger = new Logger('appsDocumentCreated')
  logger.info(`creating tokens for app ${event.params.appId}`)
  return getAdminAuth()
    .createCustomToken(event.params.appId, { claims: event.data!.data().claims })
    .then(async (customToken) => {
      logger.info('custom token created')
      return signInWithCustomToken(getAuth(clientApp), customToken)
        .then(async () => {
          logger.info('signed in using custom token')
          return getFirestore()
            .collection('tokens')
            .doc(randomBytes(24).toString('hex'))
            .set({ appId: event.params.appId })
            .then(() => logger.info('app tokens created'))
            .catch((error) => logger.error('could not create app tokens', error))
        })
        .catch((error) => logger.error('could not sign using custom token', error))
    })
    .catch((error) => logger.error('could not create custom token', error))
})
```

It works fine when running in the emulated environment. The function is deployed correctly, but nothing happens when I add a document in the Firebase console.

The first time I tried to add a document I get this log:

```json
{
  httpRequest: {9}
  insertId: "xxx"
  labels: {1}
  logName: "projects/xxx-xxx/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
  receiveTimestamp: "2023-07-12T11:15:42.135124126Z"
  resource: {2}
  severity: "WARNING"
  spanId: "xxx"
  textPayload: "The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client"
  timestamp: "2023-07-12T11:15:42.052089Z"
  trace: "projects/xxx-xxx/traces/xxx"
  traceSampled: true
}
```

After having Googled on this error message I get [information about how to make the service public](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/managing-access?_ga=2.3642419.-2032167741.1669015730#make-service-public). I have tried to temporarily add a new principle for `allUsers` with the role `Cloud Run Invoker`, but still nothing happens.

I have never needed to set additional privileges in the past to fire the Firestore triggers, and I suspect I should not need to do it now either. There are no further logs other than the singe entry I posted here.

Am I'm missing something or why wouldn't this work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, it seems that the request to your Cloud Run service is not authenticated. Here's what you can do to troubleshoot:

1. Check your Cloud Run service's authentication settings in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/%5D).

> Select your project.
>
> Navigate to the Cloud Run service you deployed.
>
> Click on the `Permissions` tab.
>
> Verify that the `Authentication` setting is set to `Allow unauthenticated invocations` if you intend to allow unauthenticated requests.

2. Verify the configuration of your Firestore trigger and ensure it's pointing correctly.
3. Review the Cloud Run logs for any relevant information or error messages.
4. Test the trigger with a direct HTTP request to isolate the issue.
5. Make sure Firestore document creation is successful and meets the necessary requirements.

For more detailed troubleshooting, refer to the following documentation:

[Firestore Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

[Cloud Run Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating)

[Cloud Run Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting)